# how to read properties from JsonObj in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have properties bag in my `lines1` objects sent to leaflet.

How can i relate to these properties when traversing JsonObj `routesMap` array?

```
function setDddCallback() {
  $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function() {
    //        var item = this.selectedIndex;
    var value = this.value;
    routesLayerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      try {
        if (layer.feature.geometry.properties.alt_id == value) {
          highlightFeature({
            "target": layer
          })
        } else {
          resetHighlight({
            "target": layer
          })
        }
      } catch (e) {}
    });
  });
}
```

In my code `layer.feature` is `undefined`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`layer.feature.geometry.properties` => according to GeoJSON spec, only Features are expected to potentially have `properties`.

From a previous question, it seems your GeoJSON objects are Geometries, not Features. That is why Leaflet does not attach a `feature` member to the built `layer`, and `layer.feature` is `undefined`.